# Is there a way to build a software defined radio using the PC's DSP chip?

Tags: rf, dsp, sdr

I'm looking to build a radio controller for a few DIY robots and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to utilize the onboard DSP in PC's as a SDR. The reasoning for this direction is I remember reading a related project back in my BBS days for ham radios.

The project would preferably be on Linux, yes I'm vaguely familiar with GNUradio, and use as little hardware as possible.

Update:

After google-ing I found the reference document I was refering to at [amsat](http://www.amsat.org/amsat-new/information/faqs/crow/LearnDSP.pdf).

However most documentation I've found is geared to Windows/DOS based projects.

Comment: There is some software for doing AFSK _modulation_ on the sound card, which then feeds into an existing ham transmitter, but I wouldn't really call that SDR.

Comment: What "DSP chip"?

Comment: If what you want is a really cheap SDR that requires little more than an ordinary PC, then that's probably the [softrock](http://wb5rvz.com/sdr/). But, there's no "DSP chip" -- just the CPU.

Comment: Wow am I really that much of a curmudgeon to remember that your PC soundcard was and still is a DSP IC? It was common in Ham Radio/AX.25 Packet Radio projects to use custom coding that worked with the sound card's DSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What PC DSP chip are you referring to?  I don't know of any DSP chip inside of commercial PCs that's capable of performing software defined radio.  It is possible to do the necessary processing for a baseband bandwidth of a handful of MHz with the CPU, but there is no getting around the need for an analog front end.  A device the the USRP has a decent FPGA with enough DSP power to handle of up to around 50 MHz of baseband bandwidth along with the ADCs, DACs, oscillators, up and downconverters, and amplifiers necessary to actually work like a radio.  You will need something to provide this functionality.

If you just want to receive, I would suggest looking at the rtlsdr project.  This project uses a TV receiver dongle that has about 1 MHz of receive bandwidth and just outputs the raw baseband samples.  It's probably the cheapest possible SDR receiver, but it has a very limited baseband bandwidth.

Comment: But RTL-SDR can't be used to transmit radio. All the dongles supported by it are receivers.

Comment: You're going to need to shell out for some hardware if you want to transmit.  A USRP is a decent choice, but a little pricey.  There was a cheaper SDR device with a transmitter on Kickstarter a few months ago, but I can't recall what it was called.

Comment: Ah, here we go: take a look at the bladeRF and the HackRF units.  I don't think either of them are generally available yet, though, but they were both funded on Kickstarter.

Comment: @alex.forencich Since the mid-90's nearly all COTS PC have a DSP chip built into the sound card. [Programming the DSP](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/lecture/lockwood/l22x.html)

Comment: I see.  So using the sound card, you would get about 20 kHz of IF bandwidth.  Not so great, but I suppose it is sufficient for some purposes.  You'd still need a front end with downconverters and upconverters that can interface with the sound card.  Still, I think the CPU itself would be far more powerful than the sound card DSP these days.